# Sum of infinite series $1+\frac22+\frac3{2^2}+\frac4{2^3}+\cdots$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How do I find the sum of $\displaystyle 1+{2\over2} + {3\over2^2} + {4\over2^3} +\cdots$

I know the sum is $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (\frac{n+1}{2^n})$   and the common ratio is $(n+2)\over2(n+1)$ but i dont know how to continue from here

Comment: You're wrong about the common ratio; only a geometric series has a common ratio, and this isn't a geometric series.

Comment: @Fundamental the question in the title is not even close to this question, how can this be a duplicate?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico-geometric_sequence

Comment: @Bot $x=1/2$ here

Comment: If a ratio depends on $n$, then it is not common. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I've posted answers to this question here a number of times. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Instead of voting to close as you should have?

Comment: @Fundamental : I'd have to be able to actually find the previous postings.  They're scattered over several years and I don't know of any particular search terms that will find those and no others.

Comment: @MichaelHardy On the [list of frequently asked questions](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=frequent), this is #1. The single most duplicated question on the site. (And still, seven answers were posted here.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After establishing convergence, you could do the following:
$$S = 1 + \frac22 + \frac3{2^2}+\frac4{2^3}+\dots$$
$$\implies \frac12S = \frac12 + \frac2{2^2} + \frac3{2^3}+\frac4{2^4}+\dots$$
$$\implies S - \frac12S = 1+\frac12 + \frac1{2^2} + \frac1{2^3}+\dots$$
which is probably something you can recognise easily...

Answer (score 7):

Consider the geometric series $$\sum_{n = 0}^\infty x^n = \frac{1}{1 - x}, \quad |x| < 1.$$

Differentiating both sides with respect to $x$,

$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty nx^{n-1} = \frac{1}{(1 - x)^2},$$

or

$$\sum_{n = 0}^\infty (n+1)x^n = \frac{1}{(1 - x)^2}.$$

Now substitute $x = \frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 5):

Once you've determined that the sum converges (you can do this by the ratio test or by integration as other users have pointed out), you can find the value quite nicely. Let

$$S=1+\frac{2}{2}+\frac{3}{4}+\frac{4}{8}+\frac{5}{16}+\cdots$$

Then

$$2S=2+\frac{2}{1}+\frac{3}{2}+\frac{4}{4}+\frac{5}{8}+\frac{6}{16}+\cdots$$

From the second term on, this shares denominators with $S$ itself, so we can write

$$2S-S=2+1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{16}+\cdots$$

But this is just a geometric series, so we get

$$S=\boxed{4}$$

Answer (score 5):

HINT: Consider the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$ and differentiate (do you know this theorem?).

Answer (score 5):

$$1+\frac22+\frac34+\frac48+\frac5{16}+\cdots$$
$$=1+\frac12+\frac14+\frac18+\frac1{16}+\cdots$$
$$\ \ \ \ \ \ +\frac12+\frac14+\frac18+\frac1{16}+\cdots$$
$$\ \ \ \ \ \ +\frac14+\frac18+\frac1{16}$$
$$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ +\frac18+\frac1{16}+\cdots$$
$$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ +\cdots$$
$$=2+1+\frac12+\frac14+\cdots=\boxed4.$$

Answer (score 2):

$\sum x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}$ if $|x|<1 $ so

$$\frac{x}{1-x}=\sum x^{n+1}$$, then
$$\frac{1}{(1-x)^{2}}=\sum (n+1)x^n$$

put $x=\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: There is not much point to repeat an answer, is there?

Comment: if you see the time i answer that question you may understand that

Comment: #erfan About 7 minutes after the other answer was posted. Perhaps you're a slow typer, though.

Comment: yes i am slow typer 
mr fast typer

Comment: @erfansoheil I didn't type any answer here at all.